# Dropdown list lost css and update panel trigger can't find control id inside gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, triggers, updatepanel

Style of dropdown in css changes when the page loads. i have tried a number of ways to solve the problem. also  i am not able to find dropdownlist id in Update Trigger... any suggestions to help me out...i am stuck at this..thank you in advance...

```
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvDetails" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True"
                    ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" ShowFooter="True" Width="855px">

                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="SNo" HeaderText="S.N." ReadOnly="true" />
                        <asp:TemplateField Items Detail"
                            ControlStyle-Width="150px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlItem" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" Height="35px" CssClass="chzn-select"
                                    Style="width: 210px;" Font-Bold="false" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlItem_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblTotalText" runat="server" Text="Total :"></asp:Label>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <ControlStyle Width="150px" />
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ControlStyle-Width="0px" Visible="true">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMRP" runat="server" Enabled="false" Visible="true" BorderStyle="None"
                                    BackColor="White" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ControlStyle Width="0px" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ControlStyle-Width="0px" Visible="true">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server" Enabled="false" Visible="true" BorderStyle="None"
                                    BackColor="White" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ControlStyle Width="0px" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                    </Columns>

                </asp:GridView>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlItem" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <br />

        <div style="margin-left: 50px; margin-top: 10px">
        </div>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnAddSalesOrder" runat="server" Text="Send Inquiry" OnClick="btnAddSalesOrder_Click"
            Style="margin-left: 30px; color: White; background-color: #088FCA;" OnClientClick="myClosure();"
            class="btn btn-info" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnPlaceOrder" runat="server" OnClick="btnPlaceOrder_Click" Text="Place Order"
            Style="margin-left: 30px; color: White; background-color: #088FCA;" OnClientClick="myClosure();"
            class="btn btn-info" />
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdtProgress" DisplayAfter="1" runat="server" EnableViewState="False">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <div style="top: 0px; height: 120%; background-color: White; opacity: 0.75; filter: alpha(opacity=75);
                    vertical-align: middle; left: 0px; z-index: 999999; width: 120%; position: absolute;
                    text-align: center;">
                    <img src="Images/loader.gif">
                </div>
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.chzn-select').select2({
        no_results_text: 'Oops, nothing found!',
        allowClear: true,
        maximumSelectionSize: 1,
        width: '130px;'
    });
```

Comment: I don't know what `select2` is but if your DOM is not ready when your script runs then the elements are not yet available. Wrap your script inside a `$(document).ready(function(){//your code here})` if needed and you can also try `$('#ddlItem').select(...)` if you need to bind to many you can use data attributes - In general I don't like using classes as selectors in JavaScript, simply because in my experience the designers change those on a whim as needed. Either use identifiers or positional selectors as those are in control of the developer and css guys should not be touching those.

Comment: Another issue could be your update panel itself. I don't remember how they work exactly but if they re-load elements you can't bind to the elements inside as they get removed and re-added, loosing their bindings along the way. In that case you might need to use event delegation and use a higher static parent as the main selector. Something similar to this might work `$('#UpdatePanel1').on('select', '#ddlItem', function(...))`

Comment: select2 is used to give style to dropdown list to make it searchable.

Comment: I tried this in my code behind and it worked.                                                     
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindGridview();
            getItems();   
        }
        this.RegisterPostBackControl();
    }
    private void RegisterPostBackControl()
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvDetails.Rows)
        {
            DropDownList ddlItem = row.FindControl("ddlItem") as DropDownList;
            ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(ddlItem);
        }
    }